# Refreshing firestoreRecyclerAdapter without restarting activity

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

The application I am trying to Build must have a spinner that dynamically changes items of a recyclerView.
At the moment, when spinner item is changed, nothing happens but when I open another activity then come back, the data is then changed
How can I make the data change at the moment the spinner selected item is changed.
below is my code

```
package com.example.tutorscape;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import jp.wasabeef.picasso.transformations.CropCircleTransformation;

public class TutorListActivity extends BaseActivity {


    private SqliteDatabase mDatabase;
    boolean isFragmentLoaded;
    Fragment menuFragment;
    TextView title;
    ImageView menuButton;

    private static final String TAG = "SignedInActivity";

    //Firebase
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    // widgets and UI References

    private RecyclerView mFirebaseList;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;

    private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkAuthenticationState();
    }

    private void checkAuthenticationState(){

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if(user == null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(TutorListActivity.this, LoginStudent.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "checkAuthenticationState: user is authenticated.");
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initAddlayout(R.layout.activity_tutor_list);
        Spinner spinner =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mFirebaseList = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        mDatabase = new SqliteDatabase(this);

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_top);
        menuButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_icon);
        title.setText("Menu Activity");
        menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!isFragmentLoaded) {
                    loadFragment();
                    title.setText("Profile");
                } else {
                    if (menuFragment != null) {
                        if (menuFragment.isAdded()) {
                            hideFragment();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("Admin");

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Model> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                .setQuery(query, Model.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Model, MyViewHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

                return new MyViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Model model) {


                holder.list_name.setText(model.getName());
                holder.list_title.setText(model.getTitle());

                holder.list_imageText.setText(model.getImage());
                holder.weeklyRate.setText(model.getWeeklyRate());
                holder.subject.setText(model.getSubject());
                holder.phone.setText(model.getPhone());
                holder.trial.setText(model.getTrial());

                Picasso.get()
                        .load(model.getImage())
                        //   .centerCrop()
                        // .placeholder(R.drawable.account)
                        // .resize(w, h)
                        .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
                        .into(holder.imageView);
            }
        };


        mFirebaseList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mFirebaseList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(TutorListActivity.this));
        mFirebaseList.setAdapter(adapter);



        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if(position==0){
                    Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("Admin");
                    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Model> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                            .setQuery(query, Model.class)
                            .build();
                    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Model, MyViewHolder>(options) {
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                            return new MyViewHolder(view);
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Model model) {
                            holder.list_name.setText(model.getName());
                            holder.list_title.setText(model.getTitle());

                            holder.list_imageText.setText(model.getImage());
                            holder.weeklyRate.setText(model.getWeeklyRate());
                            holder.subject.setText(model.getSubject());
                            holder.phone.setText(model.getPhone());
                            holder.trial.setText(model.getTrial());

                            Picasso.get()
                                    .load(model.getImage())
                                    //   .centerCrop()
                                    // .placeholder(R.drawable.account)
                                    // .resize(w, h)
                                    .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
                                    .into(holder.imageView);
                        }
                    };
                    mFirebaseList.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    mFirebaseList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(TutorListActivity.this));
                    mFirebaseList.setAdapter(adapter);
                }else if(position==1){

                    Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("one");
                    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Model> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                            .setQuery(query, Model.class)
                            .build();
                    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Model, MyViewHolder>(options) {
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                            return new MyViewHolder(view);
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Model model) {
                            holder.list_name.setText(model.getName());
                            holder.list_title.setText(model.getTitle());

                            holder.list_imageText.setText(model.getImage());
                            holder.weeklyRate.setText(model.getWeeklyRate());
                            holder.subject.setText(model.getSubject());
                            holder.phone.setText(model.getPhone());
                            holder.trial.setText(model.getTrial());

                            Picasso.get()
                                    .load(model.getImage())
                                    //   .centerCrop()
                                    // .placeholder(R.drawable.account)
                                    // .resize(w, h)
                                    .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
                                    .into(holder.imageView);
                        }
                    };
                    mFirebaseList.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    mFirebaseList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(TutorListActivity.this));
                    mFirebaseList.setAdapter(adapter);
                }else if(position==2){

                }else if (position==3){

                }else if(position==4){

                }else if(position==5){

                }else if (position==6){

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });




    }

    private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView list_name, subject, weeklyRate, trial, phone;
        private TextView list_title, list_imageText;
        private ImageView imageView;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            subject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSubject);
            weeklyRate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewWeeklyRate);
            trial = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTrial);
            phone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPhone);

            list_imageText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phoneTextView);
            list_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            list_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    final String name = list_name.getText().toString();
                    final String ph_no = subject.getText().toString();
                    final String title = list_title.getText().toString();
                    final String sweekly = weeklyRate.getText().toString();
                    final String strial = trial.getText().toString();

                    final String image = list_imageText.getText().toString();

                    final String smsNumber = phone.getText().toString();

                    Contacts newContact = new Contacts(name, ph_no, title, image, sweekly, strial, smsNumber);
                    mDatabase.addContacts(newContact);


                    //  String smsNumber = "263774233406"; // E164 format without '+' sign
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello Mr Russo.");
                    sendIntent.putExtra("jid", smsNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //phone number without "+" prefix
                    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

                /*if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error/n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                */
                    startActivity(sendIntent);


                }
            });

        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }


    public void hideFragment() {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_down, R.anim.slide_up);
        fragmentTransaction.remove(menuFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        menuButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_round_notes);
        isFragmentLoaded = false;
        title.setText("Main Activity");
    }

    public void loadFragment() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        menuFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        menuButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_up);
        if (menuFragment == null) {
            menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_down, R.anim.slide_up);
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, menuFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        isFragmentLoaded = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (isFragmentLoaded=true){
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_down, R.anim.slide_up);
            fragmentTransaction.remove(menuFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            menuButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_round_notes);
            isFragmentLoaded = false;
            title.setText("Main Activity");
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    public void signOut() {
        Log.d(TAG, "signOut: signing out");
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

        //     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(myPrefs, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        //   editor.putBoolean("isStudent", false);
        // editor.apply();

        Intent intent = new Intent(TutorListActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }


    /*
            ----------------------------- Firebase setup ---------------------------------
         */



    private void setupFirebaseAuth(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupFirebaseAuth: started.");

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(TutorListActivity.this, LoginStudent.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                // ...
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you want to update the recycler try this ,,,adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your code correctly, you want the adapter to refresh the UI once the image has loaded in this:

```
Picasso.get()
        .load(model.getImage())
        //   .centerCrop()
        // .placeholder(R.drawable.account)
        // .resize(w, h)
        .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
        .into(holder.imageView);
```

In that case you can [pass in a callback to `into`](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#into-android.widget.ImageView-com.squareup.picasso.Callback-) and call [`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) in there.

```
.into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(java.lang.Exception e) {
        Log.e("Image", "Error loading image", e);
    }
);
```

Comment: H,ow do I make the ui refresh on spinner item selected because when the spinner item is changed that is when the app is supposed to change the collection it is requsting data from

Answer (score 0):

Added adapter.startlistening(); after every item click and it now works...Each item now looks as below

```
else if (position==6){

                    Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("six");
                    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Model> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                            .setQuery(query, Model.class)
                            .build();
                    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Model, MyViewHolder>(options) {
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                            return new MyViewHolder(view);
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Model model) {
                            holder.list_name.setText(model.getName());
                            holder.list_title.setText(model.getTitle());

                            holder.list_imageText.setText(model.getImage());
                            holder.weeklyRate.setText(model.getWeeklyRate());
                            holder.subject.setText(model.getSubject());
                            holder.phone.setText(model.getPhone());
                            holder.trial.setText(model.getTrial());

                            Picasso.get()
                                    .load(model.getImage())
                                    //   .centerCrop()
                                    // .placeholder(R.drawable.account)
                                    // .resize(w, h)
                                    .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
                                    .into(holder.imageView);
                        }
                    };
                    mFirebaseList.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    mFirebaseList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(TutorListActivity.this));
                    mFirebaseList.setAdapter(adapter);



                    adapter.startListening();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

works well